# Hibernate interface mapping without using annotation parameter "targetEntity"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am recently trying to introduce interfaces for some of my hibernate mapped entities and can not figure out how to configure the mapping.

When I used the Interface without any further declarations, I always got the following Exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: ...MyInterface
```

Then I found out that everything works fine, when I define the targetEntity explicitly:

```
   @OneToOne(targetEntity=InterfaceImpl.class)
   private MyInterface myInterface;
```

Unfortunately, this solution does not work in my case: I can not define the targetEntity through annotation as I want to extract this class to an common external library that will not contain and even not know the final implementation of the interface.

So is there an alternative way for declaring which implementation should be used, that I could use outside the extracted library? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Define your mapping contract in a abstract `@MappedSupperclass`  and then override it with `@AssociationOverride` in the implementation class.

Comment: Good idea, technically. Unfortunately, I really need interfaces. Abstract superclasses won't do the trick as I would need multi-inheritance to make them fit my needs. The User (see example above) should be able to implement multiple interfaces. For example, he is both author of blogArticles and author of comments. I didn't mention this above. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how things with hibernate annotations work, but I did something similar described [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2438357)

See last post for a pretty thorough explanation.

The basic need was similar in the sense that we specified interfaces in hibernate mapping files and the implementations were classes created mostly on runtime with javassist (they were non-existent compile-time).

What you need is code that can resolve on runtime the implementation class from the interface and vice-versa and to use the hibernate tuplizer/instantiator contracts as an extension point to allow hibernate to

(a) create implementation instances when it needs to populate an entity from DB and 
(b) locate the hibernate mapping meta-data when it needs to store an entity (implementation instance) to the DB.